# Use a Spring Object to add a ServiceRoute to the RouteTable

Tags: wcf, spring.net

Is there a way to add a Spring Object to a ServiceRoute instead of a class type?

This works but my ScenarioService has to have a parameterless constructor

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/scenarioservice", 
new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof (Edu3.Core.Services.ScenarioService)));
```

I would like to use something like this but it doesn't work:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/scenarioservice", 
new Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory(), 
typeof (Edu3.Core.Services.ScenarioService)));
```

Instead of providing a class type, I would need to provide a spring object.